Is there a meaningful difference in this '@()' construction or is this a bug?
I have a function whose name parameter I want to provide tab completion for, the tab completion values are file names found in c:\temp. On top of using the files in c:\temp as values, I also want to add additional tab completion values.
Below is the function
Function foo{
    Param(
    [ValidateSet([layoutNames], ErrorMessage = """{0}"" Is not a valid Layout name")]
    $Name
    )
    $name
}

and the layoutNames class, which is used by the name parameter:
Class layoutNames : System.Management.Automation.IValidateSetValuesGenerator{
    [string[]] GetValidValues(){
        #return @((Get-ChildItem -path 'c:\temp' -File).BaseName, "valueFoo", "valueBar")        #tab completetion only suggests "valueFoo" and "valueBar"
        #return @("valueFoo", "valueBar", (Get-ChildItem -path 'c:\temp' -File).BaseName)        #tab completetion only suggests "valueFoo" and "valueBar"
        return @(                                                                                #tab completetion suggests "valueFoo" and "valueBar" and the file names.
                    "valueFoo", "valueBar"
                    (Get-ChildItem -path 'c:\temp' -File).BaseName
                    )
    }}

With the above, only the third return example works, the only difference being a new line....I think.
I spent quite some time trying to figure this out, I initially started with a return statement that looked like this:
return [string[]]("valueFoo", "valueBar", (Get-ChildItem -path 'c:\temp' -File).BaseName)

but kept changing it around as nothing was working, until I eventually worked by way to using the array operator @().
The crux of my issue is that why does the class, when declared in the following manner not work as intended with the foo function, that is suggest both valueFoo, valueBar and the files names in c:\temp
Class layoutNames : System.Management.Automation.IValidateSetValuesGenerator{
    [string[]] GetValidValues(){
        #return [string[]]("valueFoo", "valueBar",(Get-ChildItem -path 'C:\Users\INDESK\AppData\Roaming\GPSoftware\Directory Opus\Layouts' -File).BaseName)             # no files names are suggested. only 'valueFoo' and 'valueBar' are suggested
        #return [string[]]("valueFoo", "valueBar",((Get-ChildItem -path 'C:\Users\INDESK\AppData\Roaming\GPSoftware\Directory Opus\Layouts' -File).BaseName))               # no files names are suggested. only 'valueFoo' and 'valueBar' are suggested
        return [string[]](((Get-ChildItem -path 'C:\Users\INDESK\AppData\Roaming\GPSoftware\Directory Opus\Layouts' -File).BaseName),"valueFoo", "valueBar")                # no files names are suggested. only 'valueFoo' and 'valueBar' are suggested
    }}

Am on pwsh 7.4/win11

you're creating a jagged array when they're in a single line. Just use ; instead of , if you're using @(...). Then everything will work fine.

Reason why the third example works is because there is no comma before the Get-ChildItem expression. See comma operator , details:

In expression mode, as a unary operator, the comma creates an array with just one member.

$arr = @( , (0..10))
$arr[0]

# 0
# 1
# 2
# etc

It's like doing:
$item = [object[]]::new(1)
$item[0] = 0..10
$arr = @($item)
$arr[0]

# 0
# 1
# 2
# etc

If you put all expressions in a single line then you're essentially risking creating a jagged array when Get-ChildItem outputs 2 or more items:
$arr = @(
    'valueFoo', 'valueBar', (0..2)
)
$arr[2]

# 0
# 1
# 2

And if it returns no items then you would end up with a null element:
$arr = @(
    'valueFoo', 'valueBar', (& { })
)
$arr.Count # 3 (Index 2 is `$null`)

If you're using the Array subexpression operator @( ) and want to put all elements in a single line, then the best you can do is to use ; as your item separator (which symbolizes a new line / new statement):
$arr = @(
    'valueFoo'; 'valueBar'; (0..2)
)
$arr.Count # 5 (the third expression was enumerated)

$arr = @(
    'valueFoo'; 'valueBar'; (& { })
)
$arr.Count # 2 (`AutomationNull.Value` didn't count as array element)


I had no idea you can use the new line character inside @( ), how neat! these are very eye opening examples. Thank you.

To add to Santiagio's helpful answer:
Another option that avoids inadvertent creation of jagged arrays is to use array concatenation via the + operator:

If the LHS of a + operation is array-like (an array or a similar data type that PowerShell would auto-enumerate in the pipeline), the RHS is "appended" to the array:

That is, a new array is being created and returned with the RHS as additional element(s).
If the RHS is itself array-like, its elements become individual elements of the new array; that is, using + to "add" two flat arrays results in another flat array.



Therefore, you can do the following:
return [string[]] (
  'valueFoo', 'valueBar' + (Get-ChildItem 'c:\temp' -File).BaseName
)

Note that, perhaps surprisingly, , (the array constructor operator) has higher precedence than +, so the LHS array ('valueFoo', 'valueBar') does not require enclosure in (...), the grouping operator.
